# MS Word VBA - 'Normal' formatting not set and overwritten by 'heading'formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word, heading

I'm using this macro to edit text copied and pasted from PDF so that it is formatted to fill the whole line in the word document.

However, when I paste above a header the line: `Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")`
 does not work and the text is formatted as a header instead.

```
Sub Clean_PDF_Para()
'crude macro to fix paragraph markers (invisible)( so text copied from pdf is formatted to fill lines
'currently based on selected range


   With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "  "
        .Wrap = wdFindStop ' think this is required to stop it fixing (breaking) the whole selction
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal") 'added to fix the paragraph style so it doesn't take the form of a heading.
End Sub
```

Any help much appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the `" "` is selected. You must select the whole paragraph:

```
Selection.Expand (wdParagraph)
```

and then set the style.

Answer (score 1):

Include the Style you want to use as part of the Find/Replace. Word can both find formatting, and apply formatting as part of the Replacement process. That makes for compacter code and less chance of mistakes (Selection could change!).

```
  With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "  "
        .Replacement.Style = wdStyleNormal
        .wrap = wdFindStop ' think this is required to stop it fixing (breaking) the whole selction
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
```